# Turtlebot4 using ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run Turtlebot4 using ROS2 Humble?

I found that it is made for galactic and foxy, I updated Ubuntu to 22.04 and wanted to start using ROS2 Humble Hawksbill.

However I found the following code made for Galactic or foxy:

- https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4
- https://github.com/iRobotEducation/create3_sim.git

Does anyone knows if it will be in ROS2 Humble soon? Or is it any package to start testing Turtlebot4 with ROS2 Humble

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403451/turtlebot4-using-ros2-humble/) by [iggyrrieta](https://answers.ros.org/users/99497/iggyrrieta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TurtleBot4 will upgrade to Humble in the near future but I don't have a concrete timeline just yet. We're a bit busy getting the first batch of robots shipped out to customers.

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2022-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1